# Assign static method output to static member variable in php

Tags: php, class, variables, static, static-methods

I'm trying to assign the output of a static method to a static variable in PHP, but always get the error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in ./MyClass.php on line 8

```
class MyClass
{
    public static function myMethod()
    {
        return array('a' => 'b'); //some array
    }

    public static $myarr = self::myMethod();
}
```

I've also tried...

```
class MyClass
{
    public static $myarr = call_user_func(function
        {
            return array('a' => 'b'); //some array
        }
    );
}
```

...but I get the same error on line 3. I've gone through this a bunch of times and I don't see any typos, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be public static function myMethod()

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't the problem. Typo in this forum, not my class, an I've edited it. Mark Baker hit the nail on the head below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assign a value to a static variable by calling a function at declaration time.

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) (my emphasis):

> They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value -- that is, **it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated**.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
public static myMethod()
```

To:

```
public static function myMethod()
```